# Magento 2 change order item price

Tags: magento2, orders, order-items

I have an order which has the grand total that I need to fix because one of my products prices is incorrect, to do that I need to change the order item price and recollect order total, is there a way I can do this programmatically?

**Here's how I load my order:**

```
$order = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution will like below

```
$orderId = 'put_your_order_id';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quoteToOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem');
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
```

First we need to update the order quote.

```
foreach ($items as $quoteItem) {
    $origOrderItem = $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getId());
    $orderItemId = $origOrderItem->getItemId();
    //update quote item according your need 
}
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

Then update the order

```
foreach ($items as $quoteItem) {
    $orderItem = $quoteToOrder->convert($quoteItem);
    $origOrderItemNew = $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getId());

    if ($origOrderItemNew) {
        $origOrderItemNew->addData($orderItem->getData());
    } else {
        if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) {
            $orderItem->setParentItem(
                $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($orderItem->getParentItem()->getId())
            );
        }
        $order->addItem($orderItem);
    }
}
$order->setSubtotal($quote->getSubtotal())
      ->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal())
      ->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal())
      ->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal());
$quote->save();
$order->save();
```

Comment: please share all modules code. I am beginner  in magento

Comment: Hi @Gagan sorry we don't have the module code for this question, you can please check our answer.

Comment: @MagetopE-commerce where is $items defined?

Comment: For quote items: `$items = $quote->getAllItems();` and for order items: `$items = $order->getAllItems();`