# How to edit or update the ordered item data in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, order-items

I want to edit some data's of ordered items like weight, price and some more.

For that, I got the ordered item collection for the specific order.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$orderItemId = '3';
$orderItem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface')->get($orderItemId);
$orderItems = $orderItem->getData()
```

So `$orderItems` has the ordered item collection.

And then I have tried to edit the ordered items like below.

```
foreach ( $orderItems->getData() as $val ) {
    $val->setWeight(1)->save();
}
```

But the weight not gets updated.

Full Code:

```
$orderId = $_GET['id'];
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface')->load($orderId);

// Edit the order items data
foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $key => $value) {
    $orderItemId = $value->getData('item_id');
    $orderItem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface')->get($orderItemId);
    $orderItems = $orderItem->getData();
    foreach ( $orderItems as $val ) {
        $val->setWeight(1)->save();
    }
}
$orderResourceModel->save($order);
```

I've just referred this link [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241018/magento-2-change-order-item-price). But I'm not having a clear idea about the orderquote.

I'm using magento 2.3 version.

Please help me. I am a novice in magento and I am stuck at this point. Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below method to update order item data, Note: using objectManager directly is not recommended.

```
protected $_orderItems;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $orderItems
)
{
    $this->_orderItems = $orderItems;
}

public function execute()
{
    $orderItem = $this->_orderItems->create()->addFieldToFilter( 'item_id', $orderItemId )->getFirstItem();
    $orderItem->setWeight(1);
    $orderItem->save();
}
```

For testing purpose use

```
use \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
include('app/bootstrap.php');
$bootstrapp = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$objectManager = $bootstrapp->getObjectManager();
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

$orderItem = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory')->create()->addFieldToFilter( 'item_id', $orderItemId )->getFirstItem();
$orderItem->setWeight('2')->save();
```

Comment: Thanks Ranganathan. Will try this method and let you know.

Comment: Can I use the order item collection factory via object manager.
`$orderItem = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory')->addFieldToFilter( 'item_id', $orderItemId )->getFirstItem();`

Comment: Where do you want to implement this code?

Comment: For my testing purpose, I'm writing the code on magento root folder

Comment: Yes you can use objectmanager here only......

Comment: Do not Use update, create related logic in view files

Comment: But I didn't get the data on `$orderItem`

Comment: What is the error you got?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96372/discussion-between-ramya-and-ranganathan).

Answer (score 0):

**You can update or edit the existing order by following**

```
$orderId = '21';
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$quoteToOrder = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\ToOrderItem');
$order = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($orderId);
$quote = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->load($order->getQuoteId());
```

**Update the order quote.**

```
$items = $quote->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();

foreach ($items as $quoteItem) 
{
    $origOrderItem = $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getId());
    $orderItemId = $origOrderItem->getItemId();

    //update quote item according your need 
    $quoteItem->setWeight();
    $quoteItem->setQty();
    ....
}
$quote->collectTotals();
$quote->save();
```

**Update the order**

```
foreach ($items as $quoteItem) 
{
    $orderItem = $quoteToOrder->convert($quoteItem);
    $origOrderItemNew = $order->getItemByQuoteItemId($quoteItem->getId());

    if ($origOrderItemNew) 
    {
        $origOrderItemNew->addData($orderItem->getData());
    } 
    else 
    {
        if ($quoteItem->getParentItem()) 
        {
            $orderItem->setParentItem($order->getItemByQuoteItemId($orderItem->getParentItem()->getId()));
        }

        $order->addItem($orderItem);
    }
}

$order->setSubtotal($quote->getSubtotal())
->setBaseSubtotal($quote->getBaseSubtotal())
->setGrandTotal($quote->getGrandTotal())
->setBaseGrandTotal($quote->getBaseGrandTotal());

$quote->save();
$order->save();
```

Comment: But the question is how to update order items......Not how to update (order)/(quote items)...

Comment: you can edit order item as well, look at "update quote item according your need"

Comment: I've just referred this link [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/241018/magento-2-change-order-item-price). But I'm not having a clear idea about the orderquote.

Comment: But you didn't declared the `$items` variable..What the `items` variable has?

Comment: You're right Ranganathan. That was my doubt while I'm referring that above link.

Comment: the $items is a items from quote_item table of the current order, i will update the code

Comment: @user4536, for my task I need to update the order / order quote

Comment: But quote item will deleted after the order is placed....isn't it?

Comment: please try this code and let me knew if any problem occurred